# How can I convert a html table in Rmarkdown into Latex in order to output in a pdf?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, reporters

I'm working on an RMarkdown pdf document and am trying to convert a table formatted in html using the FlexTable object of the RepoRters package and want to convert it into latex so that I can ouput the table into a pdf.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!
Rafael

Comment: `library(xtable); print(xtable(df))`

Comment: @mr.joshuagordon thanks for the help, but I'm trying to use flextable because it gives more customization options than xtable. Although I'm not married to it, is it possible to use xtable to create colored rows?

Comment: I don't know if `xtable` does it, and I have no experience with `RepoRters`.    I've done this with `lazyWeave`, which might work for now.  In a few months time, I'm hoping the `pixiedust` package will do this.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31517012/row-color-of-data-frame?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @Benjamin thanks for the tip, i'll check lazyWeave out, I've never used it before. Are there any guides you would recommend?

Comment: Unfortunately,I never bothered to write any guides for `lazyWeave`, and now that I'm trying to supplant it with `pixiedust`, I'm not inclined to spend the time to do it (I've become increasingly disenchanted with my early work).  I'll write up a quick example in an answer for getting a table into latex format with the zebra striping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example that works on my machine.  Be sure to include the `header-includes` block in the YAML content.

````
---
title: "lazyWeave Example"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{xcolor}
   - \usepackage{graphicx}
   - \usepackage{colortbl}
---

After running `install.packages("lazyWeave")` the following should produce the desired table.

```{r}
library(lazyWeave)
options(lazyReportFormat = "latex")
```

```{r, results='asis'}
lazy.matrix(mtcars[1:10, ],
            rcol = c(TRUE, FALSE),
            usecol = "lightgray")
```
````

Comment: thanks for the help. That worked great for creating the zebra striping. Now the issue I'm running into is that I can't find a way to wrap text (I'm able to do this with a pander table). Do you know if this is possible using lazyweave? Thank you so much for all the help and good luck with pixiedust!

Comment: Well, it _can_ be done, but not with any ease.  The one time I did it, I had to paste the latex code into my data frame.  I think it was using \parbox and there was another latex package required.  But that was at my previous job, and I don't have access to that code anymore.